# Variable after dot

Tags: javascript, events, dom

My question is simple:
Is there a way to have the event as a variable or any variable after a dot in general?
Is there a way to do something like this?

```
var type = "onkeyup";
document.getElementById("test").type = myFunction;
```

or

```
var element = "body";
document.element.style.marginTop = 0;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("test")[type]` this should work.

Comment: Your question is not as simple as you might think. Yes, there is a way to have an event as a variable, but what has an event to do with your code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` notation instead of dot `.`. The reason is square bracket allows to deal with variable property names.

```js
var type = "onkeyup";
document.getElementById("test")[type] = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
  alert('worked')
}
```

```html
<input id='test'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the comment provided by Mr_Green above:

```
var myEvent = "onkeyup";
myInput[myEvent] = function() {}
```

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43ceL4gf/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the event as string.

> The **`EventTarget.addEventListener()`** method adds the specified [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)-compatible object to the list of event listeners for the specified event type on the [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) on which it's called. The event target may be an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) in a document, the Document itself, a [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), or any other object that supports events (such as [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)).

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('pointerdown', myFunction, false);
//                       id
//                              add an event listener
//                                               event type
//                                                              callback
//                                                                          options
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close to solution except .type use [type]

Example here

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" id="test">

var type = "onclick";
document.getElementById("test")[type] =function myFunction(){
alert("Button Clicked");
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64e2pL9n/19/) link